# Compositional Templates Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

What is the best way to create modular templates?

For example, if I have something like this:

```
#base file:
{header}
{block content}
{footer}

#main file:
{extends base}
{block content definition}

#product file:
{extends base}
{block content definition}
```

This is the django way from what I understand - filling in the blanks.

Now, my question is what if I needed a page like this:

```
{header}
{main}
{product}
{footer}
```

Basically, the main, and product are both inside the base file. I could try a deep inherit (a page that has main, which then consecutively loads product) but that does not work since the files both define 'content', and that is not possible in Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do two templates "_main.html" and "_product.html" which don't extend base, just their own content.

After that you can use them via include tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
#main.html file:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% include '_main.html' %}
{% endblock %}

#product.html file:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% include '_product.html' %}
{% endblock %}

#and what you want:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% include '_main.html' %}
    {% include '_product.html' %}
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Eek. I imagined it would be something dirty like this :/